# Is there a way to execute a command when a user logs off from X?

Tags: x11, logout

I am trying to execute two commands one on logon and one on logoff.
For the log on one, I put my script into `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` and this works.

I'd like it to be system-wide so I can use any WM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at your display manager (lightdm, gdm, kdm, xdm, wdm).

Newer lightdm versions can have a [`session-cleanup-script`](https://askubuntu.com/a/134534/16134) entry in the `[SeatDefaults]` section of `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`.

For gdm, you can put a script in the [PostSession directory](http://library.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en).

For kdm, xdm and wdm have a look at [this answer at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/65460/create-a-logoff-script-task-for-linux).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I did try to add a command in Xreset but it didn"t work.I keep digging

Comment: You can put `exec >/tmp/Xreset.log 2>&1` at the start of the script (your Xreset command), so you can see whether the script is called at all, and you can see its error messages.